# Show that $\hat{\delta_h} = e^{-2\pi i h \cdot \xi}$

Tags: functional-analysis, fourier-transform

Show that $\hat{\delta_h} = e^{-2\pi i h \cdot \xi}$, where $\delta_h(\phi) = \phi(h)$

By definition, we know that $\hat{\delta_h}(\phi)=\delta_h(\hat{\phi})=\hat{\phi}(h).$

but $\hat{\phi}(h) = \frac{1}{(2\pi)^{N/2}}\int_{\mathbb{R}^N}\phi(x)e^{-ix\cdot h}dx.$ This is really all I got; I'm not sure how this is supposed to be equal to the desired expression.

Any thoughts would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two points to be noted. They are using a slightly different definition of FT: $\hat f (h)=\int f(\xi)e^{-2\pi ih.\xi} d\xi$. Once you realize this you can use the following: If $g$ is alocally integrable fuction then we an think of $g$ as  a distribution  which acts on a test fucnction $\phi$ to give the value $\int g(\xi) \phi (\xi) d\xi$. I hope this clear up your confusions.

Comment: Okay. I think I understand a little better. So following my initial calculation, once we arrive at $\hat{\phi}(h) = \frac{1}{(2\pi)^{N/2}}\int_{\mathbb{R}^N}\phi(x)e^{-ix\cdot h}dx$ we then observe that this is just $e^{-ix\cdot h}$ acting on $\phi$, and thus $\delta_h$ acts on $\phi$ the same way that $e^{-ix\cdot h}$ acts on $\phi$. And I assume I deal with the $\frac{1}{(2\pi)^{N/2}}$ with a $u$-substitution?

Comment: @Bears Yes, you got it!

Comment: Awesome! thank you so much!